# What is missing/needs fixing in this program?

Tags: c, string, pointers, repeat

I'm setting up a program where if I type in a string, I need to use a function with these 2 formal parameters (a pointer and a character). Every time I run through the program, the code won't run through my declared function with the actual parameters.

How this works is...

1) Input my string

2) Input the character I want to see is repeated

3) The function will run a for-loop to see which characters in my string (which is in an array) contain the repeated character; every time it does, it will increment and total the number of times it was repeated. Below is my function code...

```
int main(void)
{
        char string[100], rep_char = 'c', *ptr = string[0];
        int charcnt(char *ptr, char c);

        printf("Input your string: ");  

        gets(string);

        printf("%i", strlen(string));

        printf("\nWhich character in the string are you checking for repetition? ");

        scanf_s("%c", &rep_char);

        charcnt(*ptr, rep_char);

        getch();

       return 0;
}

int charcnt(char *ptr, char c)
{
        int rep = 0;    
        char string[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        *ptr = string[i];
        if (string[i] == c)
        {
            rep++;
        }
    }
    return rep++;
}
```

I expect to run like so....

[Expected]:

Input your string: hello there.

Which character in the string are you checking for repetition? l

2

Instead I get...

[Actual]:

Input your string: hello there.

Which character in the string are you checking for repetition? l

Comment: This code shouldn’t even compile. You’re assigning a char to a char pointer, giving a function char when it wants a char pointer etc. Which compiler are you using? Does it really not complain about these things? Also always tag the language you’re using.

Comment: I was using C on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. My professor said the code should be able to run, but it's not for some reason.

On a sidenote, I'm new to StackOverflow.

Comment: And the compiler really doesn’t give any warnings? Turn them to the maximum and fix everything it warns about

Comment: See: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used). ***Validate*** every input by checking the return  Avoid `getch()` and `conio.h` which makes your code 100% non-portable to anything other than ancient DOS/windows. Instead, just use `stdio.h` and `getchar()` to hold the terminal window upon at the end of your code (same result).

Answer (score -2):

These are following issues that I found in your program.

1. You are not saving or even printing the result return by your `charcnt function`.
2. You don't event need to assign anything. Your `if condition` can be `if(ptr[i] == c)`
3. You are not even printing the result anywhere in your code.

Answer (score -2):

Check this out!

```
int main() {
char string[100], rep_char = 'c';
int charcnt(char * ptr, char c);

printf("Input your string: ");

gets(string);

printf("%i", strlen(string));

printf("\nWhich character in the string are you checking for repetition? ");

scanf("%c", & rep_char);

printf("\n%d", charcnt(string, rep_char));

getch();

return 0;
}

int charcnt(char * ptr, char c) {
int rep = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); i++) {

    if (ptr[i] == c) {
        rep++;
    }
}
return rep++;
}
```

Comment: What is void swap supposed to do? And the code for it isn't even shown

Comment: Thanks! I have edited it. Now the code works pretty fine.